# Understanding and tweaking AWS policies for job functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, security

There are quite many possibilities to configure AWS policies; Amazon has therefore provided [policies for job functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_job-functions.html).

Now is it anyhow possible to sneak into JSON code of these policies to learn in detauls what they do and use them as foundation for own policies along their lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can have a look at the JSON policy documents. On that page that you link to ([AWS Managed Policies for Job Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_job-functions.html)) click the Policy you're interested in *while being logged to your AWS account* and it will take you to the policy definition.

E.g. if you click to [**AdministratorAccess**](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess) it will open the *IAM Policies* page and show you the JSON:

[image]

Hope that helps :)

Comment: A pity it seems like you can't sort policies by their type.

Answer (score 0):

Job function related policies are visible among all others and their JSON can be shown there as well.

https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/policies